# When entering www.google.com I get www.google.co.il , why?

Tags: networking, browser, dns

Why when I hit `www.google.com` in my browser , I get `www.google.co.il` ?

OK , so I'm in Israel , but what's wrong with getting `www.google.com` ?

Does it happen because the `www.google.co.il` server is closer to me (Israel) than the `www.google.com` server ?

Comment: try this http://www.google.com/ncr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever You enter `Google.com` That will Be redirected with your Local area..
Depending On your local server it will display the server..

Weather if it is

`Israel` it will re direct to  `www.google.co.il`

`Australia` it will re direct to  `www.google.com.au`

If you want to change that will depend Up on your ISP(Internet Service Provider).
To redirect to main google site you need to change your ISP.
or else You need to USE Some third party servers. which will maintain a virtual servers like   using VPN(virtual private Network)on your system.. example(`Hideman`,`tunnelbare`,`hotspot vpn`)
If You want to redirect to www.google.com with out installing any software then

**TRY this**
at your browsr type ***`https://www.google.com/ncr`*** (*here ncr is non-country-related*)

You will be redirect to Main `www.google.com`

Here its https so don't worry..

Answer (score 2):

yes Google redirects to your local Google search page to avoid this try
Worldwide Google Search address: http://www.google.com/ncr
where ncr is non-country-related

Answer (score 1):

No. Google.com usually redirects to a local version of the Google page—like Google.in for INDIA.You can use `www.google.com/ncr` to use google.com. ncr means "no country redirection"